# How to use a fixed desktop save directory name with desktop-save-mode?

Tags: init-file, desktop

I would like to use a standard desktop save file when using Emacs as a server (with Emacsclient) and use no desktop save file (or optionally, another desktop save file) when running a regular Emacs instance (no `server-start` command).

Is it possible to use a fixed desktop save directory name with `desktop-save-mode`?

If I use:

```el
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

I have no direct control over where the desktop is saved (though, I think it is saved in `~/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop`).

I tried to add the following to my Emacs init file:

```el
(require 'desktop)
(defvar my-desktop-dir "~/emacs-server")
(when (file-exists-p (desktop-full-file-name my-desktop-dir))
  (desktop-read my-desktop-dir))
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook (lambda () (desktop-save my-desktop-dir))))
```

while this seems to work, I am not sure if desktop auto save will be enabled.. From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions) :

> When desktop-save-mode is **active** and the desktop file exists, Emacs
>   auto-saves it every desktop-auto-save-timeout seconds, if that is
>   non-nil and non-zero.

so in order to make `desktop-save-mode` active, I have to run `(desktop-save-mode 1)` in my init file. The problem is that this command then will revert to the desktop stored in `~/.emacs.d`, which is not desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `(setq desktop-path (list my-desktop-dir))` before calling `(desktop-save-mode 1)` seems to solve the issue:

```el
(require 'desktop)
(setq desktop-path (list "~/emacs-server"))
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Note: You will now get a question `Save desktop? (y or n)` when killing Emacs server and this is the first time you save the desktop..

Comment: emac 27. This isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `desktop-change-dir` to instruct emacs to load the desktop file at a given location, and remember it for auto-save later.

```
(desktop-change-dir "~/emacs-server")
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Francesco. But for some reason, this leaves me with a lock in directory `"~/emacs-server"` after I exit Emacs, such that the next time I run Emacs as a server, I get a warning: `desktop file appears to be in use. Using it may cause conflicts. Use it anyway? (y or n) `

Comment: It seems like using `(setq desktop-path (list "~/emacs-server"))` instead of `(desktop-change-dir "~/emacs-server")` solves the issue..

Comment: If you could incorporate my last comment somehow in your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Yep, `desktop-path` is the way to go.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with locks when using `desktop-change-dir`. Are you sure it's not due to some leftovers from older tries?

Comment: I could of course incorporate your comment about `desktop-path` in my answer, but it looks to me like it is a different solution. It would probably be clearer if you put it in an answer of your own, don't you think?

Comment: Ok, good point. I have added the comment as a separate answer.

Comment: desktop-path not working in emacs 27.